# upload image file location using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file, blob

I used blob data type in mysql and also i used blob in bind_para letter "b", i can see the image in folder but it cant save in database so this is the bind_para name $file below, if i replace blob "b" with letter "s" in bind_para it will save [BLOB - 20 B] so the letter "b" is not storing for image?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

here is the upload.php

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $file="uploads/".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

prepared statement:

```
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, email, password, image, birthday, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $file, $birthday, $gender);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: where is your prepared statement?

Comment: since it's the query which is the issue, it would make sense to show it. However, `$file` in your code appears to be the file path, not the content. Do you really want/need to store the file in your DB as a blob? Normally it's more efficient to store the file on disk and just store the path to it as a string in the database.

Comment: FYI, harmful files such as trojans can easily be uploaded with what you have. Else that was the intended purpose? ;)

Comment: i replace b as s for image bind param

Comment: if I put "b" nothing save in daatabase as bind_param

Comment: You are already storing the image in the file system, by moving it from the temp directory to a permanent location with move_uploaded_file. So what do you think you still need a blob for here in the first place?

Comment: You're moving the file to a folder called "uploads". So far so good. Now you need to store the path to it as a string in your database. `$file` is the path string, and you're sending it - again good. The only thing wrong seems to be that you're trying to store a string in a blob column. Just change it to a varchar column. You don't need to save the image in the database, because you've already saved in on disk. You just need to store the path to it in such a way that you can access it again later on. Forget about storing the file _content_ in the database, it's not very efficient.

Comment: if i used blob as data type in mysql why not in prepared statement as blob "b"?

Comment: because you're not passing in a binary blob, you're passing in a **string**. Read mine and CBroe's comments properly.

Comment: so the purpose of blob is for storing image or other file not file location?

Comment: Yeah, it's for binary data (of any kind, doesn't have to be something which would comprise a whole file). A file's _path_ is just a string. It's _content_ is binary data. But see my answer - I would advise against storing the content in the database if you don't absolutely have to.

Comment: ok thanks sir i will put +1 sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're moving the file to a folder called `uploads`. So far so good. Now you need to store the path to it as a string in your database. `$file` is the path string, and you're sending it to the database - again good.

The only thing wrong seems to be that you're trying to store that path string in a `blob` column. Just change it to a `varchar` column.

You don't need to save the file in the database, because you've already saved in on disk in the `uploads` folder. You just need to store the path to it in such a way that you can access it again later on.

My advice would be to forget about storing the file's *content* in the database, it's not very efficient. The way you've (almost) done it is generally a better approach.

---

P.S. Take heed of Akintunde's comment - you should write some code to check what kind of file is uploaded, and probably disallow things such as script or exe files which could contain malicious content.